# Need to know if SQL Oracle can output a certain hierarchical style

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle18c

Needing to know if this is possible.

I'm trying to get a hierarchical output looking like this:

```
TITLE|CHART|FUND|ORGN|PROGRAM
S    |S    |null|null|
S    |S    |1   |null|
S    |S    |1   |10  |
S    |S    |1   |10  |1
S    |S    |2   |null|
```

Is this possible to accomplish in SQL Oracle?

I can't figure out the proper verbiage for this and that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: I've seen people doing *magic* in SQL so I presume it *is* possible. However, what's the source (sample data) that should be presented this way?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, the above is about what the data looks like in the table I'm trying to query from.

I can't provide and actual snippet of the data since it belongs to my employer. But the issue is that all records will have a title = 'S' and a chart = 'S".
The first record will only have the chart and title, the rest are null. Then for records > 1 it will have a hierarchal layering like I tried to demonstrate above. I hope this clears it up!

Comment: Not really... please edit the question to show representative source data and matching results, and preferably your current attempt. It doesn't have to be your real data, but it does need to give an idea of the structure/relationships you're starting from. At the moment it isn't clear what hierarchy you're referring to - it looks like a simple ordering question.

Comment: Doesn't matter if the actual data is your employers'. To solve a problem you can use any data. Set up a basic example (for instance in livesql) yourself with sample data to showcase what you want. Provide use the create table script, some insert statements and the expected output. *That* we can work with.

Comment: Are you looking for this ?
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/hierarchical-queries#:~:text=%20Hierarchical%20Queries%20in%20Oracle%20%201%20Setup.,can%20represent%20a%20problem%20when%20querying...%20More%20

Comment: thanks @Namandeep_Kaur that's a lot more helpful than what i've found in my own research!

Answer (score 0):

Your sample result doesn't look hierarchical,
hierarchical queries usually have a tree structure and a `CONNECT BY` clause.

You can probably get the required result by using the `ORDER BY` clause as follows:

```
SELECT TITLE, CHART, FUND, ORGN, PROGRAM
  FROM employers_data_table
 ORDER BY TITLE
         ,CHART
         ,FUND ASC NULLS FIRST
         ,ORGN ASC NULLS FIRST
         ,PROGRAM ASC NULLS FIRST
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this, the answer I found was to use unions.

Thanks Crowne for your answer, it definitely helped.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31594095)